# Install Samba 4.7.6 to help diagnose an issue. Is there a repository and how do I do it?

Tags: 22.04

I need to install an old Samba version,4.7.6 .  I thought I knew how to do this but can't find a repository and I am not quite sure how to make it work.
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
This is just a band aid fix until we can get some software updated.

Comment: Nope. 22.04 was release with Samba 4.15. I don't think older versions are available.